# How to determine if an affine transformation would cause reflection?

Tags: geometry, transformation, affine-geometry

I have a list of affine transformation matrices and I want to write a code to delete the transformation matrices that applying them on an image would cause reflection.
after seeing [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtCU4.png) in Wikipedia I get the intuition that if

```
mat[1][1]*mat[2][2] < 0
```

then the matrix should be deleted. but in some cases this test fails: [link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGsWg.png)

so what is the correct way to do this test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the determinant and if it's negative, then there's a reflection.  The determinant for a 2x2 matrix $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)$$ is $ad-bc$.